# python socket server over internet

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking

So i would like to create a small online game. (I am a complete noob with networking)

I got a server-client connection going if they are both on the same network but would need to do it over the internet. How do i do this?

server.py

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = "0.0.0.0"
port = 5000
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connection from", addr)
    c.close()
```

client.py

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = "192.168.1.66"
port = 5000
s.connect((host, port))
s.send(bytearray("Message", "ascii"))
```

I have tried using my public IP but i cannot connect.

Comment: You need to port forward your server socket.

Comment: @fuzzything44 could you elaborate? I am a complete noob (sorry!)

Comment: I would use ngrok: https://ngrok.com/

Comment: here is the thing. This is more of a networking problem then a programming. Why do I say that.
Try to setup software that you know work. A webserver for instance; now try to make it available to the internet. Once you have solved that problem, you will understand the answer to your problem.

Comment: @Apero could ou explain how i could use it? i've just downloaded it

Comment: Client-server programming over the internet is a problem with many facets, several of which have *nothing* to do with programming per se (as @DavidBern says). What remains relevant to programming are issues like latency, resilience, concurrency and security to name a few.  Whole books have been written about network server programming. As-is, this question is almost certainly too broad.

Comment: @RolandSmith I understand that. My aim is to have a server running and they have multiple clients connected. the clients may send a message in world chat, want to battle another person. things like that

Comment: @JoshuaNixon, well try to simplify your problem. Make available on your local network to do the exact same thing. Just ignore "internet" for a while. Make it work, then look at this youtube video, https://youtu.be/BGvFYRIrl20?t=1m50s

Comment: @DavidBern Ok so i am under the impression that i have forwarded port 5000 to port 10000 but still cannot connect

Comment: run "ngrok http <local port>" this will associate a public url that you can hit from the outside world

Comment: Okey @JoshuaNixon: Did you follow my advice? Did it really work to connect on the internal network? If so, this is a question best asked on http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/port-forwarding because the problem isnt solved with less/more code. If it didnt work, I would advice you to take a look on Beejs guide http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/ everything is in C-lang. Might be hard to understand but Beej is explaining everything you need to know. Python is working with sockets in the same way but they made it little easier. When you have a programming related problem, update your question.